# How to execute setupSpec() only once for all inheritable classes in Spock

Tags: groovy, spock

My tests are located in different classes which extended from `BaseSpec` class that in turn extended from `Specification` class of Spock Framework.

```
class BaseSpec extends Specification {
    def setupSpec() {
        println('run setupSpec() from BaseSpec')
    }

    def cleanupSpec() {
        println('run cleanupSpec() from BaseSpec')
    }
}
```

```
class FirstTestClass extends BaseSpec {
    def setup() {
        println('run setup() from FirstTestClass')
    }

    def cleanup() {
        println('run cleanup() from FirstTestClass')
    }

    def 'do test1'() {
        given:
        println('run "do test1" from FirstTestClass')
    }
}
```

```
class SecondTestClass extends BaseSpec {
    def setup() {
        println('run setup() from SecondTestClass')
    }

    def cleanup() {
        println('run cleanup() from SecondTestClass')
    }

    def 'do test2'() {
        given:
        println('run "do test2()" from SecondTestClass')
    }
}
```

As expected `setupSpec()` and `cleanupSpec()` are executed for each inheritable class.

```
run setupSpec() from BaseSpec
run setup() from FirstTestClass
run "do test1" from FirstTestClass
run cleanup() from FirstTestClass
run cleanupSpec() from BaseSpec

run setupSpec() from BaseSpec
run setup() from SecondTestClass
run "do test2()" from SecondTestClass
run cleanup() from SecondTestClass
run cleanupSpec() from BaseSpec
```

Is there a way execute `setupSpec()` and `cleanupSpec()` only once? Or I can only put all feature methods in one class?

Thanks!

Comment: Interesting. Can I ask why you'd want to?

Comment: But in answer to your question, I don't believe you can

Comment: Yep, just in ```setupSpec``` I'd like to open connection to server. Currently it looks strange that connection is opened and then closed during run tests from each class. This is historical structure for tests.

Comment: I'd be wary of opening a connection that lasts for all the tests. Moving it to a base class sounds very sensible, and then tests which _must_ use the same connection can be in the same specification

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you should do that, I agree on that with Tim. But if you insist, you can do something at the very beginning/end of Spock execution if you implement a [global extension](http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.3/all_in_one.html#_global_extensions):

Just use the `start()` and `stop()` methods. You could also keep global state and use `visitSpec(SpecInfo)` to do what you want just for a certain group of tests - whatever your creativity comes up with.

Let me know if this pointer leaves you with follow-up questions.

Comment: Thanks for advice! One more question. What if I need one shared object (client for connection) for all tests. So, object should be initialized only once and be available in all tests (in all test classes). Object should be destroyed after execution all tests. Am I right that implementation GlobalExtension doesn't help in this case?

Comment: What makes you think that? What I told you solves exactly that case. Please read again, also follow the link.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to run `setupSpec` once, you can do something like this in your `BaseSpec` class:

```
static INITIALIZED_BASESPEC = false

def setupSpec() {
    if (!INITIALIZED_BASESPEC) {

        //Do setup stuff
        
        INITIALIZED_BASESPEC = true
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems that this not work. May anyone confirm or deny that it actually works ?